# How to make a conversion without using UPDATE

Tags: sql-server-2008

Here is an original condition.
Note: In case the Key(all the columns that are keys -columns that have the key word in the column name) is NULL  set it as 'UNKNOWN' , In Case the Amount (all the columns that are amounts) is NULL set it as 0
If data type is different make a conversion(cast) in order to set the requested value. Don't use UPDATE.

Answer (score 1):

If you need it just for selection then you can use [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

`SELECT COALESCE(key_field, 'UNKNOWN') FROM table_name`